# Draw 15V from USB C Power Delivery devices

Tags: power-supply, usb, charger, power-delivery

I need to draw 15V from USB C PD capable devices such as power banks or chargers.

So I need a rather small tool or build for this I can draw about 15V 3A via usb c with.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you looking for some type of dummy load for testing purposes?

Comment: I'm looking to turn the power delivery device into a power supply for a lamp. The problem is that the lamp at default does not support any of the power delivery protocols to request 15 or 20V. So I'm looking for some sort of module which will take care of that.

Comment: Unfortunately, recommendations for specific products are off-topic here, so your question may be removed. This site is specifically for electrical engineering design questions per the site tour: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB Type C 3.1 PD to get DC20V output](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/439293/usb-type-c-3-1-pd-to-get-dc20v-output)

Comment: @ChrisFernandez I mean I don't even know if there are parts doing this as I could find none. So I'm looking for a way to do this either out of 1 or multiple parts and how to do it. As I'm actually building a custom lamp I wanna power with a phone charger or a power bank. If that's not electrical engineering then I dont know.

Comment: @PogchampLetsgodude looking for a strategy to approach the design is on topic, as are questions related to understanding how to implement the USB PD spec. The only part that's off topic is asking for a specific part, because parts change all the time and those questions don't hold up well long term. I recommend you edit your question to include the information from these comments to clarify your requirements into a specific design question.